# How can I import my old tweak written and compiled on iOS device with Theos into Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have some old tweak which doesn't work on iOS 8.4 and I wanted to debug it and possibly fix it. I am in no way good with writing tweaks, this was something I did for a friend and me and people used it since I published it on BigBoss.

Anyway at the time, I did not have OS X device and I written everything on iPhone using vi over ssh and then I compiled it on iPhone with Theos.

Now I have OS X device and I wanted to import this into Xcode. Is this even possible? If so how can I do this in most easiest way? I already have iOSOpenDev. Here is folder tree:

```
├── Makefile
├── NoIconLabels.plist
├── Tweak.xm
├── Tweak.xm.bak
├── _
│   ├── DEBIAN
│   │   └── control
│   └── Library
│       ├── MobileSubstrate
│       │   └── DynamicLibraries
│       │       ├── NoIconLabels.dylib
│       │       └── NoIconLabels.plist
│       ├── PreferenceBundles
│       │   └── NoIconLabels.bundle
│       │       ├── Info.plist
│       │       ├── NoIconLabels
│       │       └── NoIconLabels.plist
│       └── PreferenceLoader
│           └── Preferences
│               └── NoIconLabels.plist
├── control
├── me.itn.noiconlabels_0.1-2_iphoneos-arm.deb
├── me.itn.noiconlabels_0.1-3_iphoneos-arm.deb
├── me.itn.noiconlabels_0.1-4_iphoneos-arm.deb
└── noiconlabels
    ├── Makefile
    ├── NoIconLabels.mm
    ├── Resources
    │   ├── Info.plist
    │   └── NoIconLabels.plist
    ├── entry.plist
    └── obj
        ├── NoIconLabels.bundle
        │   ├── Info.plist
        │   ├── NoIconLabels
        │   └── NoIconLabels.plist
        ├── NoIconLabels.mm.46c9b2c9.o
        └── NoIconLabels.mm.ea49af4e.o
```

Thanks!